# FGDC Metadata Upgrade

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-9.3, metadata

This is something I notice recently. I'm at a stage where I'm finally moving on from ArcGIS 9.3.1 to 10.1. I noticed an assiue during this transition. In order to view my metadata, I will need to upgrade my FGDC metadata to the new format which i am aware of (ArcGIS Metadata format). However, once I upgraded, I noticed a clear issue in which some of the content (especially time and date got modified).You can see this in the xml file. Any idea how i could work around this issue ? Ideally i'll like upgrade so that users can read the metadata in ArcCatalog and at the sametime preserve all the content within my FGDC metadata. If not possible, what's the work around solution to this ?

Comment: You should not need to update the metadata just to view it, just scroll farther down to see and expand that category which should be grayed out, say "(Read Only)" next to it, and be collapsed by default. Depending on your view settings that is. If you haven't already you might take a look at the [help files on metadata](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003t00000029000000) which discuss [upgrading formats](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/The_ArcGIS_metadata_format/003t0000002w000000/).

Answer (score 1):

Watch out that ArcCatalog has a default option that **does** update some of the metadata fields **when you view the metadata sheet**. Check out the ArcCatalog options > metadata tab > uncheck the tick box "[Automatically update when metadata is viewed](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/003t/GUID-62990CDC-84DD-4705-8300-AEA033E960DE-web.png)".

More on automatic metadata update in ArcGIS [in the online help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_automatic_metadata_updates/003t0000000q000000/).